# Predict function in R gives wrong output and Backfit inverses X and Y from curve during Interpolation

Tags: r, interpolation, predict

I am trying to use a model to interpolate data to a known sigmoid curve with 5 points.

I am using R Version 1.0.136 for Mac. And used the package drc to find a model that fits my Data.

`model1 <- drm(Abs ~ Concen, fct=LL2.4(), data=Data1)`

I get a reliable 5 point curve. So, I am sure the curve is what I want, and it comes from plotting the model.

[image]

Standard Curve

It is when trying to interpolate when problems come. I have a matrix .csv including several columns, one is Abs with 85 rows (5 from the curve and 80 values) and the other is Conc which has only the 5 rows from the curve filled and 80 empty cells. When I use the function predict I get two problems:   
  
 `predict (model1, newdata=Conc2, se.fit = TRUE, interval='prediction', type="response",  level = 0.95)`

1. I only get the first 5 values (the ones from the curve) and the rest filles in with NAs
2. I get a prediction for X (Abs) instead to get it for Y (Conc).

i.e.

```
     |Prediction    |        SE      |
     :--------------:----------------:
 [1,]| 0.40365782   |    0.006283406 |
 [2,]| 0.28834945   |    0.005787962 |
 [3,]| 0.22156106   |    0.005147014 |
 [4,]| 0.10895382   |    0.004807142 |
 [5,]| 0.08248443   |    0.005639122 |
 [6,]|      NA      |        NA      |
 [7,]|      NA      |        NA      |
 [8,]|      NA      |        NA      |
 [9,]|      NA      |        NA      | ....
```

I might need to specify a data frame, but I am unsure of how that works in this case. I tried data.frame(Abs,Concen) and I had all my results pretty much equal between them independently of X (Abs).  
  
So, I decided to use the backfit function.  
  
    `backfit(model1)`  
  
    |    | dose |  Estimate   |  
    :----:------:-------------:  
    |[1,]|    0 |    NaN      |  
    |[2,]|    1 |  0.04172716 |  
    |[3,]|    3 |  1.04366913 |  
    |[4,]|   30 |  3.53619494 |  
    |[5,]|  100 |  4.44513138 |  
  
And there are two problems there:  
  
1.- The estimates are inversed! 1 should be the higher and 100 the lower Abs.  
2.- Again, it only gives results for the curve values and does not continue to the other 80 rows.  
  
 
It is when trying to interpolate when problems come. I have a matrix .csv including several columns, one is Abs with 85 rows (5 from the curve and 80 values) and the other is Conc which has only the 5 rows from the curve filled and 80 empty cells. When I use the function predict I get two problems:   
  
    `predict (model1, newdata=Conc2, se.fit = TRUE, interval='prediction', type="response",  level = 0.95)`  
  
1.- I only get the first 5 values (the ones from the curve) and the rest filles in with NAs.  
  
2.- I get a prediction for X (Abs) instead to get it for Y (Conc).  
e.i.  
  
     |Prediction    |        SE      |
 [1,]| 0.40365782   |    0.006283406 |  
 [2,]| 0.28834945   |    0.005787962 |  
 [3,]| 0.22156106   |    0.005147014 |  
 [4,]| 0.10895382   |    0.004807142 |  
 [5,]| 0.08248443   |    0.005639122 |  
 [6,]|      NA      |        NA      |  
 [7,]|      NA      |        NA      |  
 [8,]|      NA      |        NA      |  
 [9,]|      NA      |        NA      | ....  
   
I might need to specify a data frame, but I am unsure of how that works in this case. I tried data.frame(Abs,Concen) and I had all my results pretty much equal between them independently of X (Abs).  
  
So, I decided to use the backfit function.  
  
    `backfit(model1)`  
  
    |      |dose        |   Estimate    |  
           :------------:---------------:  
    |[1,]  |  0         |      NaN      |   
    |[2,]  |  1         !   0.04172716  |  
    |[3,]  |  3         |   1.04366913  |  
    |[4,]  |  30        |   3.53619494  |  
    |[5,]  |  100       |   4.44513138  |  
  
And there are two problems there:

1. The estimates are inversed! 1 should be the higher and 100 the lower Abs.
2. Again, it only gives results for the curve values and does not continue to the other 80 rows.

Comment: First off, R's formulas are generally arranged like `Y ~ X` or `outcome ~ predictor`. It seems like you are expecting the opposite from some of your comments. Can you clarify which variable you expect to be X and which Y?

Comment: I have verified X and Y are dependent and independent as they should. But in the results they get inversed, indded. I don't understand why. I found similarcase from 2011, but was not answered.